# AngularJS Run execute function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

why in this script:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module( "test", [] );  

        app.run(
            angular.element.prototype.test = function ( ) {
                alert ( "da" );
            }
        );

        app.directive('cacat', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="test">
        <cacat></cacat>
    </body>
</html>
```

function test is called?
I want this function called only when I want.

**Answer**

```
        app.run(
            function () {
                angular.element.prototype.test = function ( ) {
                    alert ( "da" );
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: why `I haven't other details.` mentioned 7 times?

Comment: is `angular.element.prototype` a common way to interact with angular?

Comment: @PankajParkar , stackoverflow says: You have more code than information, what more information?

Comment: @dandavis Yes, angular.element -> JQLite

Comment: @PankajParkar Maybe to meet the minimum length requirement for a post.

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to add addt. methods to the `angular.element`  so that they become available for any directive they define?

Comment: Just for giggles, I set up a test case and it indeed provides a means to add addt. APIs to the angular element for use inside a directive's link function via `link:function($scope, elem, attrs) { elem.newFunc() }`.  That's actually pretty neat. http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/GomQGj?editors=101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment statements can be evaluated to their values.
If you do something like

```
var x = false;
if(x = true) { /*Some code here*/ }
```

`x` is assigned, *then evaluated*, in the `if` statement.

In your sample,

```
app.run(angular.element.prototype.test = function ( ) {
            alert ( "da" );
        })
```

evaluates the function that you assigned to `angular.element.prototype.test`, effectively passing that function to `app.run()`. `app.run()` takes it and, as one would expect, runs it.

If you simply wanted it to *make* the assignment *in* the `run()` execution, you need to instead pass it a function that does that, like this:

```
app.run(function(){
    angular.element.prototype.test = function ( ) {
        alert ( "da" );
    });
});
```

Comment: I just putted that function in another function, and it works

Comment: Great, that's exactly how it should be. If this answered your question, you should mark it as the answer so people will know it's resolved.